# Problem with creating dictionary with gensim for LDA

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, corpus

I have a problem running gensim to create a Dictionary and the Doc Term Matrix.

When I run:

```
from gensim import corpora, models
import gensim
clean = ['door', 'cat', 'mom']
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(clean)
```

I get:

```
doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string
```

In the real problem, Clean is still a list-type variable. It's all the words in a large corpus after applying a tokenizer, tagger, removing punctuation, etc.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item in the corpus should be a sequence of unicode tokens (words), not a string.

If you want the strings `'door'`, `'cat'`, & `'mom'` to be the words in the dictionary, you could do:

```py
from gensim import corpora
corpus = [
    ['door', 'cat', 'mom'],
]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(corpus)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just need to split:

```
from gensim import corpora, models
import gensim
clean = ['door', 'cat', 'mom']    
corpus = [d.split() for d in clean]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(corpus)
```

Comment: That's somewhat roundabout way to acheive what you likely really want - where each item in the corpus is itself a list of string tokens: one text of a multi-text corpus. Only if your training data is just one long list of words will your approach work - and even then, it'd be clearer to wrap your one list in another. That is, replace your use of `split()` (in line `corpus = [d.split() for d in clean]`) with `corpus = [ clean, ]`.